# Running UIMA job on Hadoop with Behemoth

Tags: hadoop, uima

I have a fully functional UIMA job that does simple annotation. I can successfully launch it via my local CAS GUI.

I have been trying to run the UIMA job on Hadoop using Apache Behemoth. I am wondering if  someone has worked on this? The job runs successfully but in the hadoop output directory; there is no output from the UIMA job. I can see in the Hadoop job tracker output that the job completed successfully and it copied its input data to the final output directory.

Can someone point me to what could be going on here, and is there any additional changes we need to make in our UIMA code?

Thanks

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am using Hadoop and want to use some code that is designed for UIMA.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps that work for a small pipeline that I put together:

- Export your UIMA pipeline as a jar (Your-pipeline.jar)
- Copy to HDFS
- Generate Behemoth Corpus (** remember all the paths below are hdfs paths **)

  ```
  hadoop jar tika/target/behemoth-tika-1.1-SNAPSHOT-job.jar com.digitalpebble.behemoth.tika.TikaDriver -i /user/blah/ -o /user/blah/
  ```
- Process using your-pipeline

  ```
   hadoop jar uima/target/behemoth-uima-1.1-SNAPSHOT-job.jar com.digitalpebble.behemoth.uima.UIMADriver /user/blah/ /user/blah/ /apps/Your-pipeline.pear
  ```
- List Annotations:

  ```
  hadoop jar uima/target/behemoth-uima-1.1-SNAPSHOT-job.jar com.digitalpebble.behemoth.util.CorpusReader -i -a /user/blah/
  ```
- Convert your annotations to text:

  ```
  hadoop jar uima/target/behemoth-uima-1.1-SNAPSHOT-job.jar com.digitalpebble.behemoth.uima.UIMABin2TxtConverter -a -i /user/blah/ -o /user/blah/
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this scenario:

1) Gererate Behemoth corpus

2) Run Tika job over Behemoth corpus => Tika corpus

3) Run UIMA job over Tika corpus => UIMA corpus

4) Review UIMA Output corpus via Behemoth's CorpusReader with -a option - it shows founded UIMA annotations which you defined in behemoth-site.xml in /hadoop/conf.

But the problem that I do not know how to extract founded annotations from Behemoth(UIMA) corpus.

I also has CAS Consumer(in the PEAR file) which should write UIMA Annotations to the file on the local file system(not in HDFS) but I haven't found this file on my filesystem((